# How do I configure log4j to start with some text and end with some text?

Tags: log4j

I'd like to make a log4j output file that is XML and give it a root element.
Hence, I'd like it to start with a tag and end with a tag.

What do I put in my log4j.xml to make this happen?

Right now, all I have is this:

```
 <appender name="FILE" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
  <param name="File" value="logs/file.log" />
  <param name="Append" value="false" />
  <param name="MaxFileSize" value="5000KB" />
  <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
   <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%m%n" />
  </layout>
 </appender>
```

Comment: You can edit your questions rather than reposting them...

Answer (score 0):

Change that `PatternLayout` to an `org.apache.log4j.xml.XMLLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the api of XMLLayout:

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/xml/XMLLayout.html

It clearly explains that you need to include the resulting xml output within another document (by using xml entity). So in your parent document you can place a root element of your choice.

This will also allow you to use [chain saw](http://logging.apache.org/chainsaw/index.html).